# Tracking a cell in excel js

Tags: office-js

For our project is necessary can identifier a cell of excel (for example through a Id, tag or similar)

We are using the cell position for assign a name to one table. If add or delete a column in the sheet the cell position change and we are not able identifier the tableName.

how can we set/get a property unique for the cell?

We have tried use NamedItems but not able identify the name selecting the cell, we need know the nameditem selecting the cell.

We need set some property to cell, next delete row and columns. Next we need get that property selecting the cell.

Thanks

Comment: Would you please share with me more about identify the name selecting the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Office JS world.

This is a well-known gap, not only office js but also VBA developer has this requirement. therefore our team is now investigation for metadata API in this Q.

however, the effort for building this feature is not trival, due to a) file format change, 2) co-auth support 3) backward compatibility 4) ensure perf when handling big amount of metadata. so it won't likely release in a short time.

Therefore if you want to have short term workaround, I would suggest the following options:

1. nameditem (seems you have tried)
2. hidden row and column
3. hidden worksheet

but each of them has limitations. There was also some discussion on metadata solution that you may refer to [VSTO: Attach meta-data to a cell in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045435/vsto-attach-meta-data-to-a-cell-in-excel)

meanwhile, I would also recommend you to submit your request on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563)